# Multiple users working in the same JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Trying to work on a networking project, where two or more users need to be able to paint in the same JFrame.

How would this be approached most realisticly, connecting the two PCs using their IPs, then create a real-time scenario for them to work in, OR, some kind of package system, where the users send what they've drawne recently, and then the other user can see what have just been send?

EDIT: Added my drawing class for context

```
public class CanvasFrame extends JPanel {

    ArrayList<Point> location = new ArrayList<Point>(); 

    JTextArea consoleOutput = new JTextArea(1,20);

    public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {
        consoleOutput.setEditable(false);
    }

    public CanvasFrame() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                location.clear();
                location.add(e.getPoint());
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                location.add(e.getPoint());
                repaint();
            }
        });
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500));
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if(location.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }

         Point p = location.get(0);
         for (int i = 1; i < location.size(); i++) {
             Point q = location.get(i);
             g.drawLine(p.x, p.y, q.x, q.y);
             p = q;
         }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        InetAddress SERVERIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing with friends");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new CanvasFrame(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

                JTextArea IPadress = new JTextArea(1,20);
                IPadress.setEditable(false);
                IPadress.append("DEVICE IP: " + SERVERIP.getHostAddress());
                frame.add(IPadress, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                frame.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're trying to do some kind of digital/network whiteboard? Depending on the complexity, you need to setup some kind of protocol which allows the computers to share information. The most likely scenario might be to share vector based information which allows the computers to update their individual models and update what needs to be painted. Depending on what you want to achieve will drive how you will do it. Personally I'd be focused on sending the most recent set of full changes, but drawing text, for example, may require more regular updates the day drawing a polygon

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've added my drawing class for context. As you can see, it's an array of points.